# EditText не обновляется при SetText

Tags: android, android-edittext

В программе несколько табов фрагментов в `ActionBar`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть `EditText` с событием `OnClick()`, по которому открывается диалог выбора даты.
При первом открытии в `onCreateView()` ставлю текущую дату (*09.09.2015*), список должен быть пустой:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    String dtBeg = edtDateCheck.getText().toString();
    edtDateCheck.setText(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
```

Меняю дату на *08.09.2015*, список обновился, все ок. Потом переключаюсь на другие фрагменты и снова возвращаюсь в исходный фрагмент.
В отладке вижу, что вызывается `edtDateCheck.setText(sdf.format(c.getTime()));`
Дата ставится *09.09.2015*, и список пустой, так как `edtDateCheck.getText()` возвращает *09.09.2015*, но на экране показывается *08.09.2015*.

Что сделать, чтобы `EditText` отображал корректную дату?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот описание фрагмента:

```
public class Check2 extends Fragment {
EditText edtDateCheck;
TextView txtCheckItog;
SearchView svName;

ListView lvCheck;
MyCheckAdapter myAdapter;
ArrayList<CheckItem> myArrList;
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> checkdata;
MainActivity activity;
ProgressDialog pDialog;

public Check2() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_check2, container, false);


    edtDateCheck = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edtCheckDate);
    lvCheck = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvCheck);
    txtCheckItog = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtCheckItog);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    String dtBeg = edtDateCheck.getText().toString();
    edtDateCheck.setText(sdf.format(c.getTime()));


    edtDateCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment(getView(), R.id.edtCheckDate, new DatePickerFragment.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick() {
                    // ПРИ СМЕНЕ ДАТЫ ОбНОВЛЯЕМ ИНФОРМАЦИЮ
                    Refresh_Adapter(); //  обновление списка

                    Integer cnt = myAdapter.getCountPersons();
                    txtCheckItog.setText("Всего отмечено: " + cnt.toString());
                }
            });
            newFragment.setCancelable(true);
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datepicker");
        }
    });



    //  Фильтрация списка
    svName = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.svCheck);

    svName.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
             myAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });

    Log.d("LIFECICLE", "CHECK_onCreateView");
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    MyTaskCheck tsk = new MyTaskCheck();
    tsk.execute();

    Log.d("LIFECICLE", "CHECK_onViewCreated");
}


class MyTaskCheck extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (pDialog == null) pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog.setMessage("Обновление. Подождите...");
        pDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Refresh_Adapter(); //  обновление списка
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try{
            lvCheck.setAdapter(myAdapter);
            Integer cnt = myAdapter.getCountPersons();
            txtCheckItog.setText("Всего отмечено: " + cnt.toString());

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("LIFECICLE","Error - " + e.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Переключение между вкладками делается так:

```
public class TabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private Fragment fragment;
    private MainActivity activity;

    // The contructor.
    public TabListener(Fragment fragment, MainActivity activity) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    // When a tab is tapped, the FragmentTransaction replaces
    // the content of our main layout with the specified fragment;
    // that's why we declared an id for the main layout.
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // clear back stack
        SearchView svName = (SearchView) activity.findViewById(R.id.svName);
        if (svName != null){
            svName.setQuery("", false);
            svName.onActionViewCollapsed();
        }

        activity.clearBackStack();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    }

    // When a tab is unselected, we have to hide it from the user's view.
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        ft.remove(fragment);
    }

    // Nothing special here. Fragments already did the job.
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Код фрагмента в студию. Подозреваю, что в onCreate методе фрагмента происходит установка текущей даты в EditText.

Comment: Так и есть,  в OnCreateView ставится текущая дата. Почему старая то показывается?

Comment: Чтобы получить ответ на ваш вопрос, вам нужно либо ждать телепатов, которые считают ваш код фрагмента прямо с вашего компьютера, либо добавить этот код в вопрос. Телепаты здесь появляются очень редко.

Comment: прошу прощения, выложил код

Comment: @Suvitruf: ping, код фрагмента появился.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что само поле EditText восстанавливает значение предыдуще значение (смотрите - [onRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Parcelable))).

Вам нужно правильно обрабатывать onSaveInstanceState и onCreate внутри фрагмента и если фрагмент обновляется (проходит через цикл onSaveInstanceState -> onCreate) то обновлять данные в соответствии с этой логикой, а не пытаться поставить начальные значения.

Comment: Fragment сам сохраняет и восстанавливает состояние до уничтожения?

Comment: @ВикторНекрасов Да, в методе onSaveInstanceState().